# How to add specific flags to moc in a qmake project?

Tags: qt, qmake, moc

I compile a Qt executable using `qmake && make` on the following `project.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH *= ../../dependencies/boost
QT *= opengl xml
CONFIG *= qt opengl static

TARGET = myexe
HEADERS = Viewer.hpp MainWindow.hpp Inspector.hpp
SOURCES = main.cpp Viewer.cpp MainWindow.cpp Inspector.cpp
```

However, when compiling, `moc` chokes on a boost macro which it cannot parse. To work around [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-22829), I need to pass the flag `-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED` to moc, but I cannot manage to do so.

How to I edit my `.pro` file to pass a given flag to `moc`? (but not to `g++`, as `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` does)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit hackish, but what about if you overwrite the moc compiler so that it includes the flag. In the .pro:

```
QMAKE_MOC = $$QMAKE_MOC -DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Comment: A bit hackish, but at least it's a start. Thanks!

Comment: Is working for me on Qt5: make sure to `load(moc)` before you `QMAKE_MOC += -DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED`

Comment: Better solution, QMAKE_MOC_OPTIONS += -DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED

Comment: For cmake you can just add: ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED)

Answer (score 3):

In my code in header files I just have:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
    //Here we include Boost or Ogre headers with Macro
#endif
```

It works perfectly in Qt5 x64 and need not recompiling anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is an update to this issue for boost 1.53, see the last post [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829):

We need to add `-DBOOST_NO_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION` also.

Answer (score 1):

For add specific flags to moc in a qmake project(qt5.2) need:

```
    load(moc)
    QMAKE_MOC += -DBOOST_INCLUDE_GUARD_GOES_HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to do this is based on a comment on the accepted solution from David Faure:

```
QMAKE_MOC_OPTIONS += -DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED
```

The other proposed methods that involve `load(moc)` and manipulating the `QMAKE_MOC` variable itself have an unfortunate side effect: they prevent qmake from automatically adding `INCLUDEPATH` variables (and maybe others) that would normally be on moc's command line, if `INCLUDEPATH` is set up *after* the call to `load(moc)`.

This approach composes easier if you have your qmake configuration split up to multiple files; you don't need to ensure that the change to the moc command line comes after all `INCLUDEPATH` directories are set.

Answer (score 0):

See for example [the Qmake docs for variables](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html) which details

- ten different variables in the `QMAKE_CFLAGS_*` pattern, and
- ten different variables in the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS*` pattern

and hence I would start with `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` which is documented as:

> `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`
>
> This variable contains the C++ compiler flags that are
>   used when building a project. The value of this variable is typically
>   handled by qmake or qmake.conf and rarely needs to be modified. The
>   flags specific to debug and release modes can be adjusted by modifying
>   the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE` variables,
>   respectively. Note: On the Symbian platform, this variable can be used
>   to pass architecture specific options to each compiler in the Symbian
>   build system. For example:
>
> ```
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS.CW += -O2
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS.ARMCC += -O0
> ```
>
> For more information, see qmake Platform Notes.

So I'd start with

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED`

which you can just add to your `.pro` file.

Comment: That adds the flags to all C++ compilations, not only to `moc` calls but also `g++` calls, which is totally undesirable (and could break the build if I used the boost features guarded by `BOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED`. So, how to pass flags to `moc` but not to `g++`?

Comment: Well, maybe you can't in which case you may have to either create a shell script `moc` that calls the `moc.real` binary with the added option, or try an `#ifdef` in the code that gets unset if `g++` is use d (to protect the compilation) but active when `moc` is used.   Or use the `-D` flag I suggested but `#undef` it in a header file if `g++` is used.

Comment: Yeah, I already have a work-around strategy in place. I'd like either a clean way of doing it, or a confirmation from an experienced user that it's not possible at all (which would seem weird).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are doing Ogre3D (OGRE 1.8.1 SDK for Visual C++ .Net 2010 (32-bit) ) then use QT5 32bit instead of the QT5 64bit version, it will pass.

Also consider this :

```
#ifndef BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 1
#endif
```

I think it has been compiled (boost included) with 32bit thus i suppose i have to take src and recompile (using my 64bit) but thats another story where i wont go for now since OGRE 1.9 RC 1 SDK for Visual C++ .Net 2012 (64-bit) will be soon release on stable version.

Regards

EDIT 1 :

Downloaded Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows and configured my QT creator (the one coming with full QT5 and guess what …. Ogre3D is working like a charm when compiling on 4.8.4.

```
Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 485 MB)
Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (VS 2010, 234 MB)
OGRE 1.8.1 SDK for Visual C++ .Net 2010 (32-bit)
```

I also mentionned it for who is interested here : http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/128660/