# QT5 migration and Boost: if.hpp: Macro argument mismatch bug

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt5, c-preprocessor

In qt 4.8 I used boost (1.52) It all was ok... Now I try to move to QT5 and get `if.hpp: Macro argument mismatch` error on line `131 BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_SPEC(3, if_)`. In some [QT forums](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829) there is presented a solution like this:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
// All boost includes
#endif // Q_MOC_RUN
```

in each my file that uses boost... So question here is - how to tell to boost that QT is not ready for `BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_SPEC` and that boost shall use some more primitive preprocessor syntax one that would be QT5 compatible?

---

Update: found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618170/1056328) yet it seems not to bring any effect at all in Qt5=(

Answer (score 6):

Here is the best workaround I've been able to find after scouring the net for a few hours. It is basically what other folks have been saying, but with a few clarifications.

- The problem has to do with moc.exe not correctly handling Boost macros.
- In order to get around this, we disable inclusion of Boost headers by defining their include guards for the moc.exe process, but not for regular source compilation.
- This can be accomplished most easily by adding the following code to your project file (e.g. myproject.pro):

  ```
  # ensure QMAKE_MOC contains the moc executable path
  load(moc) 

  # for each Boost header you include...
  QMAKE_MOC += -DBOOST_INCLUDE_GUARD_GOES_HERE
  ```

For example, if I want to use the logging library, I'd have:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
```

If I open up the header file, I can see at the top that the include guard is named `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL_HPP_INCLUDED_`. Therefore, the corresponding line in the .pro file would read:

```
QMAKE_MOC += -DBOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL_HPP_INCLUDED_
```

A couple of more notes in case they are relevant for anyone:

- If you find this not working, make sure to run qmake and rebuild your project whenever you add a new line to your project file.
- I'm using Boost 1.53 with Qt 5.0.1 and building for MSVC2010 within QtCreator on Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: can't you just add `-DBOOST_MPL_IF_HPP_INCLUDED` to only exclude the offending file?

Comment: This is was the best solution of the two presented here for my purposes. Cheers to OP.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with the same problem and found that when I removed the definition of 
`_MSC_VER=1700` from the custom build command for moc that the warning went away for me.

I was able to remove this from all the custom build moc steps by overriding the qmake.conf variable `QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES`.  I am using a .pro file to generate a .vcxproj file and compiling my project using Visual Studio 2012 ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339832/how-to-generate-sln-vcproj-using-qmake) is how to generate a .vcproj/.vcxproj file from a .pro file).

In the qmake.conf file associated with win32-msvc2012 this variable is as follows:

```
QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES += _MSC_VER=1700 _WIN32
```

In my .pro file I overrode it with this:

```
QMAKE_COMPILER_DEFINES = _WIN32
```

Then I regenerated the .vcxproj file and it compiled with no macro argument mismatch warnings.

I am using VS 2012, boost 1.51, and qt 5.1.2 (compiled from git@gitorious.org:qt/qt5.git).

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the same problem and found helpfull info on the Qt-forum.

Here are Qt bugreport and Qt-forum thread with helpfull description and workarounds of the problem:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29331

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22993/

Comment: Specifically adding the `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN` directive worked for me.