# Why is my MOC_DIR ignored when generating Visual Studio projects with qmake

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013, qmake, moc

I'm generating Visual Studio 2013 projects with Qt 5.3 `qmake`. In my `.pro` file, I've got the following line:

```
MOC_DIR = $$BUILD_DIR/<DEBUG OR RELEASE>/moc
```

If I `message($$MOC_DIR)`, the path is correctly formed. However, when I build in VS, the `moc_<CLASS>.cpp` files are not generated in that location, but instead end up in the same directory as the `.pro`. I get the following warning during compilation:

> Two or more files with the name of `moc_<CLASS>.cpp` will produce outputs to the same location

That's not surprising, because if I look at the contents of the generated `.vcxproj`, I see the following (irrelevant tags/text elided `...`):

```
<CustomBuild Include="..\include\Class.hpp">
    ...
    <Outputs Condition="...Release...">moc_Class.cpp;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
    ...
    <Outputs Condition="...Debug...">moc_Class.cpp;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
    ...
</CustomBuild>
```

Why does is my custom `MOC_DIR` being ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other VS2013 projects generated with Qt5 `qmake` were placing the `moc_<CLASS>.cpp` files in the specified location, as expected, so my suspicion was that something else in the `.pro` was interfering.

I'm using Boost (1.55) and while adding Boost to the project, I came across the issue described in this SO question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056834/qt5-migration-and-boost-if-hpp-macro-argument-mismatch-bug?lq=1).

I added the following lines to the top of my `.pro`:

```
load(moc)
QMAKE_MOC += -DBOOST_MPL_IF_HPP_INCLUDED
```

... and that sorted out my macro argument mismatch bug. It also caused the bug described here. Calling `load(moc)` *before* setting `MOC_DIR` for some reason causes `qmake` to ignore the custom `MOC_DIR`. If you reorder `load(moc)` to be after `MOC_DIR` is set, everything works as expected.

My `.vcxproj` now looks as it should, my `moc_<CLASS>.cpp` files now placed into the correct `<BUILD>/debug/moc` or `<BUILD>/release/moc` directories.

**However:** I still get the same `MSB8027` build warnings. This appears to be a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797460/incorrect-warning-msb8027-reported-for-files-excluded-from-build) in Visual Studio. It confuses the situation, though, as I only broke the moc locations when I added `load(moc)`, but I got the warning before the problem was introduced, while it existed, and now even after it's fixed! For now I'm disabling the warning; see Felix Huang's answer [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797460/incorrect-warning-msb8027-reported-for-files-excluded-from-build).