# How to add specific flags to moc in a vs2010 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, moc, qt-vs-addin

I'm trying to resolve [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829) and a workaround suggested was to pass `-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED` to moc.exe.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8486992/942596) question is related to mine. The difference is I want to add a MOC flag in a VS2010 project (VS add-in).

I've tried **left click -> Qt Project Setting -> MocOptions** and adding `-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED`

Note my problem occurs using boost 1.53.

Comment: Actually your solution worked for me (I am using Qt 4.8.4 with VS2010 and boost 1.53)

Comment: Are you sure you rebuilt you whole project after editing MocOptions? Do you use boost in precompiled headers?

Comment: @Corijn, yes I am using boost in the precompiled headers. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has been provided yesterday from [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829)

We need to add `-DBOOST_NO_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION` to the moc options too.

Answer (score 1):

What you've tried is actually the right solution. However, you need to rebuild your project in order to work around the bug. When DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED is set, it changes the precompilation of your Boost headers. As you stated, you are using boost in precompiled headers. You have to rebuild them as well to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply but that is not the solution for me. It seems someone updated the post in the first link i gave with the solution. we need to add -DBOOST_NO_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION when using boost 1.53.

Comment: That confuses me. DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED works for me (and I do have Boost 1.53 Rev: 81650 2012-12-01 13:28:55 +0100). But you had to rebuild the precompiled boost headers, right?

Comment: Yes, but rebuild the pre-compiled headers alone did not work. Are you using `boost/lexical_cast.hpp` in your project?

Comment: This is extremely bizarre then. I am using Qt 4.8.2 which version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.8.3. I think I just don't use boost/lexical_cast.hpp in the files which are processed by the MOC compiler.